# What does MCU stand for?

Tags: terminology

I see the acronym MCU being used a lot on Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange.

What does it stand for?

Comment: Why unclear? It may be a bad question (lack of research on OP's side), but two answers justify that it is answerable.

Comment: @TimSparrow There was second, quite different question added, before edit.

Comment: If you run into any other abbreviations you don't understand, try looking here first: [List of common abbreviations](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1530/57310)

Answer (score 7):

As you can see from Acronymfinder.com,

MCU = [**Marvel Cinematic Universe**](https://www.acronymfinder.com/Marvel-Cinematic-Universe-(fictional-franchise)-(MCU).html).

Comment: Or try to use the tag [mcu] on a question...

Comment: Telling someone to "just google it" is pretty damn rude. I've edited out the snark and left in the useful content.

Comment: @Valorum I disagree. Sometimes, people just need a wakeup call. If someone doesn't realise their question has been answered many times before on the net, a reminder that it does is not pretty damn rude.

Comment: @Valorum: I politely disagree: tone is very difficult to detect in text; and for the record, I wasn't being rude...

Comment: @djm - I don't really see how the tone of "just google it" could be taken as anything other than a rebuke.

Answer (score 3):

MCU = Marvel Cinematic Universe

Comment: Why the downvote? Although repetitive, this does answer the question and it is quite right on point.

Comment: We downvote answers to off-topic questions to discourage people from answering them.

Comment: Except it's not **off-topic**...it's poorly researched but it's perfectly clear and entirely SF&F related. The Question should be downvoted to oblivion but not a perfectly reasonable Answer.